# disable text selection on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have script that toggles menu from the side:

```
<script>
    // Closes the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-close").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

and I use this in every section tag:

```
ondblclick = $("#menu-close").click()
```

but the problem is that when I double click somewhere it also selects text. The question is: How can I disable this double click selection on the whole page? It'd be cool if I could implement it into my actual script.

UPDATE:
now I have

```
document.getElementById("el").ondbclick = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    alert()
    return false}

$("#menu-close").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
// Opens the sidebar menu
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

and id="el" on elements I don't want to be selected.. but it still doesnt work

Comment: There are CSS rules you can use to achieve this - as noted by @CodeiSir - but don't put them on the entire document as it's bad for UX. Just add them to the button which may be double clicked.

Comment: I forgot to say that the concept of my web is that you double click anywhere and it toggles menu.. so I can't use it on any kind of button

Answer (score 31):

Use these CSS-Rules on the Element:

```css
#menu-close {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Do this on every Element that should not be selected. Or just on `body {` for everything.

---

You could also remove the double-click selection after it happened, if you don't want to disable selection everywhere:

```js
document.getElementById("el").ondbclick = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
  alert()
  return false
}
```

```html
<div id="el"> asd</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't apply it to the correct Elements. You didn't provide your HTML-Code, if you do we can help you better

Comment: I forgot to say that the concept of my web is that you double click anywhere and it toggles menu.. so I can't use it on any kind of button or certain element..

Comment: @YamiteruIori I added another option

Comment: @YamiteruIori did it work for you? If so maybe accept the answer

Comment: no sadly it didn't.. my web is actually on but im still working on it ;) yamiteru.com

Comment: This is simple and neat solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
(element).querySelector('mousedown', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

In Plain JavaScript...

Comment: This disables text selection for double click, but not for large screen selections. Perfect! Just like the Atlaskit button https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/core/button

Answer (score -2):

You can apply class like this

```
.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: This'd disable selection globally.. I wanna disable it only on double click